# Application Verifier for Mobile 5.0 cannot connect to my WM 6.0 device

Tags: debugging, windows-mobile

I’m trying to connect with Application Verifier for Mobile 5.0 to Windows Mobile 6.0 Professional device and I fail. Is this even possible?

ActiveSync and VS2005 debugging on this device work fine.

I’ve setup Application Verifier transport and startup server as Microsoft ActiveSync, if I click Test button it says “Connection to device established” but if I try to connect to the device, it says: “Unable to launch device EXE”.

Could you tell me how to connect to this device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the appverif_client.exe has not been copied to the device.

Check out 
http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsphone/archive/2009/07/26/windows-mobile-application-verifier.aspx

For the latest information and tools on getting this working. It also includes some additional pointers on getting it working.